# Knockout foreach binding, update value

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I got ko model:

```
var Model = function(notes) {
    this.note = ko.observableArray(notes);
}; 

var model = new Model([{"post":"a"},{"post":"b"}]);
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

And html div:

```
<div data-bind='foreach: note'>
    <p><span data-bind='text: post'>
    <p><input data-bind='value: post'>
</div>
```

Here's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DE9bE/

I want to change my **span** value when new text is typed in **input**, like in that fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/paulprogrammer/vwhqU/2/
But it didnt updates. How can i do that in foreach bindings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The properties of the objects need to be made into [observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html).

You could do this yourself manually (i've used the plain js array [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method here, if you need IE8 support you can use `ko.utils.arrayMap` for the same purpose):

```
var Model = function(notes) {
    this.note = ko.observableArray(notes.map(function(note){
        note.post = ko.observable(note.post);
        return note;
    }));
}; 
var model = new Model([{"post":"a"},{"post":"b"}]);
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DE9bE/3/)

---

Or you can use the [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) (seperate js file that you need to include) which does this (recursively) for you.

```
var Model = function(notes) {
    this.note = ko.mapping.fromJS(notes);
}; 
var model = new Model([{"post":"a"},{"post":"b"}]);
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DE9bE/2/)

---

If you get the whole data object from the server you could also feed it directly:

```
var model = ko.mapping.fromJS({
    note: [{"post":"a"},{"post":"b"}]
});
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DE9bE/4/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I see where was a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

### HTML

```
<div data-bind='foreach: note'>
    <p><span data-bind='text: post'></span></p>
    <p><input data-bind='value: post'/></p>
</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
 var Model = function (notes) {
      this.note = ko.observableArray(notes);
 };
 var Post = function (data) {
     this.post = ko.observable(data);
 };

 var model = new Model([new Post("a"), new Post("a")]);
 ko.applyBindings(model);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DE9bE/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

What you want is an observable array with observables, or else your span will not be updated since you are changing a non-observable variable, see this post.

[KnockoutJS - Observable Array of Observable objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048553/knockoutjs-observable-array-of-observable-objects)