# knockoutjs observable array of observable objects binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, observable

I have an issue in that when I am adding a object containing observable properties to an observablearray the interface is not being updated.

I have studied similar questions on this forum ([KnockoutJS - Observable Array of Observable objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048553/knockoutjs-observable-array-of-observable-objects)) but I still cannot get the syntax correct, so after a day of trying I am turning to the expects for help please.

I have created an exmaple of what I am trying to achieve

https://jsfiddle.net/ryrpnbr9/23/

When you press the Add button a BatchItem object is created and is added to the BatchItems observablearray of Batch.  I can see that the object is being updated.

I have a table with the following binding defined

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Batch.BatchItems()">
    <tr>
        <td><span data-bind="text: DocumentType"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: ItemType"></span></td>                            
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `self.Batch.BatchItems().push(bi);`, you'll have to call `self.Batch.BatchItems.push(bi);`

The difference between the two:

The first pushes directly to the array that is *inside* the observable array. This works, but knockout won't be able to tell something's changed...

The second one uses the `push` method inside `ko.observableArray`. This `push` method again pushes to the inner array, but it also calls `valueHasMutated`. This triggers the dependency updates required to update your models and UI.

*Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eLt3Luqw/) with the removed `()`*